# Router navigation isn't working as supposed to

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

I am using lazy Loading. When my app initializes I am redirected to main/home. 
I am trying to add a page to redirect new users to before redirecting them to the main/home page. 
I used a simple button to test the navigation but it always navigated me back to main/home.

***My main problem is just the navigation part***

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?. I am using ***Angular 8*** and ***Ionic 4***

***app-routing.module.ts***

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', loadChildren: './pages/main/main.module#MainPageModule' },
'./pages/search/search.module#SearchPageModule' },

{ path: 'cat-view', loadChildren: './pages/cat-view/cat- 
view.module#CatViewPageModule' },

{ path: 'country-selection', loadChildren: './pages/country-s 
 election/country-selection.module#CountrySelectionPageModule' },
  ];
```

***Main module***

```
 const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: 'main',
   component: MainPage,
   children: [
     { path: 'home', loadChildren: '../home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
     { path: 'favorites', loadChildren: 
   '../favorites/favorites.module#FavoritesPageModule' },
   ]
   },
   {
   path: '',
   redirectTo: '/main/home'
    }
  ];
```

***app.component.ts***

```
 initializeApp() {
     this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.statusBar.styleDefault();
        this.notificationSetup();
        this.navigateToNextPage();
     });
 }
 navigateToNextPage() {
    this.router.navigate(['/country-selection']);
  }
```

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but currently the loadChildren syntax from the Angular docs seems a bit different. Can you check to see if it helps? https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#routes-at-the-app-level

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the question if you want to solve some test code or implement a new user onboarding experience.

## Routing Issue

For your routes, I think you have defined your routes twice, and overridden them in the second one. What do you mean by "main module"?

## User Onboarding Tutorial

The way to do the new users tutorial is using an auth guard and saving a token in Ionic Storage.

There is a great tutorial here which directs the user to an intro slideshow for the first load only:

[Ionic Intro Slider for New Users | AngularFirebase](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/ionic4-intro-slides-tutorial-to-educate-app-users/)

Basically what it does is you create a guard:

```
// ...omitted
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TutorialGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private storage: Storage, private router: Router) {}

  async canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Promise<boolean> {

    const isComplete = await this.storage.get('tutorialComplete');

    if (!isComplete) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/tutorial');
    }

    return isComplete;
  }
}
```

And then also on the last page of the slideshow you set it to not show next time with:

```
await this.storage.set('tutorialComplete', true);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, although my problem was with routing only, the link that you mentioned is very helpful and I am defintley going to implement it now.
Thanks a lot

Comment: if this helped, consider upvoting it, it doesn't mean it totally resolved your issue but it does mean "this answer is useful" and I get a point towards my ionic4 badge :)

Comment: I am trying to implement the what you sent me in the link, and it is not working. I don't know if it is compatible with Angular 8

Comment: It is compatible with Angular 8 as far as I know. Do you have any more details, any error messages or anything?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue actually by simply removing the

```
 { path: 'country-selection', loadChildren: './pages/country- 
 selection/country-selection.module#CountrySelectionPageModule' },
```

from  **app-routing-module.ts** and adding it to the ***main.module.ts***
and then calling it this way

```
 this.router.navigateByUrl('main/country-selection');
```